# Search Function in Java Data Structure

Tags: java, search, data-structures

I have created a large amount of People beans and was wanting to store them in some kind of data structure where I would be able to search for particular types of People beans (e.g. People beans with a last name of "Sanchez") as fast as possible (I don't want to use a DB by the way). Is the only way to loop over my beans and test `currBean.getLastName().equals("Sanchez")` for each bean?

I would like to be able to do something like the following:

```
List<PeopleBean> myPeople = myBeansDataStructure.getAll(new PeopleBean("John", "Sanchez", 36),
                            new Comparator<PeopleBean>() {
                                @Override
                                public int compare(PeopleBean b1, PeopleBean b2) {
                                    // search conditions
                                }
                            });
```

and have it return a collection of beans matching the search. My searches will always be of the same 'kind', i.e., I will be either searching for beans with a particular last name, first name, or age (or some permutation of the three) so could something using an overridden equals method in the bean be used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am surprised this isnt there in the library.. or is it?

Anyway, you can write your own

```
public interface Condition<T> {
    public bool satisfies(T t);
}
```

And write a generic searcher, which goes through the entire  and applies this function to each of them and returns you a new  of only the ones that return true.

Comment: Java 8 provides similar functionality; see my answer as a reference.

Comment: @JoshM Yup I saw that.. Nice rep number by the way :P

Answer (score 2):

You can use Java 8 (This is under the assumption that `myBeansDataStructure` is a `Collection` of some sort.):

`List<PeopleBean> myPeople = myBeansDataStructure.stream().filter(person -> person.getLastName().equals("Sanchez")).collect(Collectors.toList());`

Or you could try something like this:

`List<PeopleBean> myPeople = myBeansDataStructure.stream().map(PeopleBean::getLastName).filter(lastName -> lastName.equals("Sanchez")).collect(Collectors.toList());`

Comment: :( some mean upvoter broke your leetness.. guess I can +1 now

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
    List<PeopleBean> list=new ArrayList<>();
    for(PeopleBean i:list){
        if(i.getName().equals("whatEverName")){
            //do something 
        }
    }
```